# What is the difference between the term API in MVC vs a third party application?

Tags: api, model-view-controller, architecture

I don't quite understand the difference between the term API in the context of MVC where you separate the view and the model controller vs interacting with a third party application like an air flight carrier.

Both are pretty much the same in that there is an API provider(the backend framework and the air flight carrier) and the difference is just the client being part of the app vs a separate app like the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you got it right: **[API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)** stands for: **A**pplication **P**rogramming **I**nterface.

The "application" can be local (imported library) or remote (server).

Comment: In the case of an MVC API, the browser sends a request and the front end framework would receive it. Then does the front end framework send another request to the server side application or does the front end framework just work as a router?

Comment: @yamaoka it could be either or, depends on the architecture of the server-side.